# Como puedo ir dividiendo una cadena para obtener la información?

Tags: java

Pues tengo un gran dificultad, necesito dividir una cadena para poder sacar la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formato que nos dieron, no lo podemos cambiar.

En total son seis datos. y la verdad no logro dividirlos.

Comment: En cual formato son los datos? Cual caracter separa cada columna? Y por favor agrega los codigos que ha probado.

Answer (score 0):

Para dividir una cadena de caracteres, puede usar el método '.split' al que le pasas como parámetro uno o mas caracteres, mediante los cuales se realizará la división de la cadena.
Esto generará como resultado un array con tantas posiciones como divisiones genere dicho método.

```
String cadena = "Hola Mundo";
String [] alm = cadena.split(" "); //ubico un espacio
```

Como resultado en el array alm obtienes dos posiciones. En la primera se encuentra "Hola"  en la segunda posición "Mundo".

Con estos conceptos adapta el código a tus necesidades.